# Windows - Find all files prefixed 10 random characters followed by images.aspx

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I have been cleaning up after a security issue.
I found hundreds of files with random letters/numbers followed by images.aspx ie

BHBTPL4953images.aspx

in lots of random places in inetpub\vhosts*

what command can i run to find **********images.aspx in all sub-folders in c:\inetpub\vhosts\

Comment: What have you tried, where are you stuck? Have you done any research before asking? What about `dir /S /A:-D "C:\inetpub\vhosts\??????????images.aspx"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest that you use `where.exe`, which uses the `?` wildcard as exactly one character, as opposed to `dir` which uses it as zero or one. The difference is that `where` will count **exactly** ten leading characters, whereas `dir` will return those with **up to** ten.

```batch-file
"%SystemRoot%\System32\where.exe" /R "C:\inetpub\vhosts" "??????????images.aspx"
```

Answer (score 1):

In powershell you can use `Get-ChildItem` (like dir) combined with a `Where-Object` on a regex pattern.

```
Get-ChildItem c:\inetpub\vhosts\* -Recurse | where {$_.name -match '^\S{10}images.aspx$'}
```

**Regex explanation**

The up caret `^` means the next character has to be at the start of the line.
`\S` says match anything but a space.
`{10}` means match this many occurrences of the previous character (or character set)
`$` means the previous character must be followed by the new line character.

This will exclude BHBTPL49531images.aspx since it is 11 characters between start of line and images.aspx

It will also exclude BHBTPL4953images.aspxabc since images.aspx is not at the end of the line.

This will output a list of matching fileinfo objects. If you just want the name simply add the name property reference.

```
Get-ChildItem c:\inetpub\vhosts\* -Recurse |
    Where-Object {$_.name -match '^\S{10}images.aspx$'} |
        Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name

(Get-ChildItem c:\inetpub\vhosts\* -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.name -match '^\S{10}images.aspx$'}).Name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

set "root_dir=c:\inetpub\vhosts\"
set "target_len=21"

for /r "%root_dir%" %%x in (*images.aspx) do (
    if "%%~xx" neq "" (
        call :strlen "%%~nxx" len
        if !target_len! equ !len! (
            echo %%~nxx
        )
    )
)

exit /b %errorlevel%


:strlen
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
:: strLen String [RtnVar]
::             -- String  The string to be measured, surround in quotes if it contains spaces.
::             -- RtnVar  An optional variable to be used to return the string length.
Set "s=#%~1"
Set "len=0"
For %%N in (4096 2048 1024 512 256 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1) do (
  if "!s:~%%N,1!" neq "" (
    set /a "len+=%%N"
    set "s=!s:~%%N!"
  )
)
Endlocal&if "%~2" neq "" (set %~2=%len%) else echo %len%
Exit /b
```

Comment: this will give me anythingIMAGES ie myimages.aspx 

I need something thats set to 10 characters followed by images.aspx